# How to set base path for .NET Core and Identity

Tags: .net, blazor

In a Blazor Server App running .NET6 I am using app.UseBasePath("/app") to add a subdirectory to the app's base URL.  So it goes from being .com to .com/app.  This seems to work fine at first.  The app launches and the url is at /app as intended.  However, it is not working with the pages contained in the Areas folder.  I'm using Microsoft Identity for authentication and authorization.  I have scaffolded several of the Identity pages, including Login.cshtml, Register.cshtml, etc.  These scaffolded pages are not Blazor components so Visual Studio puts them all inside an Area folder named Identity.  See attached screenshot.

[Solution folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cji5A.png)

For example, the home page Blazor component is in /Pages/Index.razor.  Normally this page is reachable at http://localhost:5000/.  After changing the base path with app.UseBasePath("/app") it becomes accessible at http://localhost:5000/app instead.  This is what I want and it's working for all Blazor components.  However, it's not working for any pages in the /Areas folder.  The Register page is in /Areas/Identity/Account/Register.cshtml.  By convention this page is normally accessible at http://localhost:5000/Identity/Account/Register.  After changing the base path I expected it to load at http://localhost:5000/app/Identity/Account/Register but links pointing to /Identity/Account/Register are still pointing to the old url without /app included.

Here is my Startup.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var identityConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>    
    options.UseMySql(identityConnectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(identityConnectionString)));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UsePathBase("/app");

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection(); // NGINX will handle HTTPS redirection

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Is there another file in the solution where I need to configure the base path for the areas?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>`, this adds the default UI to your application.

Here is a link to `AddDefaultIdentity` source.  You can see a call to `AddDefaultUI()`: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI/IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.cs,53

Here is a link to `IdentityDefaultUIConfigureOptions`: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI/IdentityDefaultUIConfigureOptions.cs,32

You can see the `LoginPath` URL is set there.  To answer your q, maybe you could try moving the line `app.UseBaePath("/app")` before `AddDefaultIdentity`.